# In my view, why does Laravel overwrite variables I declare in my controller with those from my model?

Tags: php, laravel, scope, laravel-blade

Am I understanding the MVC design pattern incorrectly? Why does Laravel seemingly overwrite variables I declare in my controller and pass to my view with those from my model? Say I'm passing the variable `$journey` from my controller to my view like so:

```
class JourneyController extends BaseController {

    public function journey($id) {

        $journey = Journey::find($id);

        // I overwrite one of the attributes from the database here. 
        $journey->name = "Overwritten by the Controller";

        return View::make('journey', array(
            'journey' => $journey,
            'bodyClass' => 'article'
        ));
    }    
}
```

But, I'm using an accessor to also modify the `$journey->name` attribute in my Journey model:

```
class Journey extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'journeys';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getNameAttribute($value) {
        return 'Overwritten by the Model';
    }

}
```

So when my view is created, and I display `$journey->name` like so:

```
{{ $journey->name }}
```

I'm left with:

```
"Overwritten by the Model";
```

Why does this occur? Doesn't the controller handle a request, fetch information from my model, manipulate it, and then pass it to the view where it can be outputted? If this is the case, why, and also how, is the model seemingly 'jumping' in between to overwrite my controller-written variable with its own?

Comment: Should perhaps your method be named `setNameAttribute`?  Normally `get` accessors don't take a `$value`.  Plus, you say you're using an "accessor to *modify*", but a `get` should not be modifying.

Comment: @MatthewBrown then how do I modify information stored in my database for display? I don't want to save the modified data, just to display it.

Comment: @bishop I'm not looking to save my modified information to the database, only to retrieve it for display. Kind of like storing the URL to an article in the database and then manipulating that URL using file_get_contents to display the actual article.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I just found a solution on Laravel 4.2 today.

```
class Journey extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'journeys';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getNameAttribute($value = null) {
        if($value)
            return $value;

        return 'Overwritten by the Model';
    }

}
```

You should update your getNameAttribute function as above to return the set value (if there is one) instead of always returning the string. Previously, calling this value would always run the function and ignore the set value, but now the function takes checks first for the value that you have set.

Hopefully 2 years isn't too late to still help some people!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using Presenters,  Take [Jeffery Way's Presenter Package](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter).  Install it normally and then you can add the `$presenter` variable to your model.

**For instance:**

```
use Laracasts\Presenter\PresentableTrait;

class Journey extends Eloquent {

    use PresentableTrait;

    protected $presenter = "JourneyPresenter";
}
```

**Then you can create your JourneyPresenter Class:**

```
class JourneyPresenter {

    public function journeyName()
    {
        return "Some Presentation Name";
    }

}
```

In your view you can call this, like so:

```
<h1>Hello, {{ $journey->present()->journeyName }}</h1>
```

It really helps keep this sort of "presentation" logic out of your view and controller.  You should try hard to keep your controller solely for its intended purpose, handling routes and basic guards and keep your views logic-less.

As for your problem, you may just be experiencing the natural order of Laravel operations.